# Do you know any designe pattern for AOP?

Tags: design-patterns, aop

Do you know any designe pattern for Aspect Oriented Programming? Do you know a book or a list of such design patterns? I am looking for design patters which specifically could be implemented in AOP. I am not interested in implementing classical DPs in AOP. I'm looking for problems which could be solved much more easier using AOP. Even a single design pattern is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Foundations of AOP for J2EE Development](http://www.springerlink.com/content/v7436h45532h8643/).  It lists many possible design patterns handled via AOP.

Comment: It would be more useful to make the link text the title of the book rather than "this book".

Comment: Sorry. Probably, I didn't provide enough details about my question. I actually am looking for design patters which specifically could be implemented in AOP. I am not interested in implementing classical DPs in AOP. I'm looking for problems which could be solved much more easier using AOP.

Comment: The referenced book shows that.  Just realize that no design pattern is AOP ONLY - since the code introduced by AOP is code you could always implement, as well.

Comment: Adding to that, IoC containers nowadays cover some of the same scenarios as AOP. Eg, a Controller in an MVC framework could be instantiated using either technology. Some frameworks even allow you to mix both

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can use the Proxy and Decorator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not enough to have a powerful tool for cleanly modularising **cross-cutting concerns** which are really numerous in most applications? This ***is*** the main pattern.

Other patterns conveniently implemented via AOP such as the Worker Object and Wormhole Pattern can be found in Ramnivas Laddad's wonderful book [AspectJ in Action (2nd edition)](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/).